# How to edit assets/notifications/styles.css?

Tags: shopify

Please tell me where I can find this file: `assets/notifications/styles.css` (styles for notifications)
I cannot see it in Themes->Edit code for MyTheme.

I need to add styles into it but cannot find it.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `assets/notifications/styles.css` in Shopify.

It's not possible even to have a folder inside the `assets` folder, so I don't know where did you get this path from.

If you are referring to the `Settings -> Notifications` templates, those styles are written inline since they are email templates. You can modify them only from the admin panel from `Settings -> Notifications` and update each separate template. ( there is text editor for each separate template there )

Comment: 1. Thanks,  friend! You help me!   2. i get this path from here: https://help.shopify.com/en/manual/sell-online/notifications/edit-template#style-email-templates-using-inline-css